# Is there an (idiomatic) way of aliasing a module's submodule in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a project with modules and submodules, where I would like to conveniently access the submodules through their parent module. To achieve that I currently have methods in my modules, which reference each of their submodules.

```rb
module ParentModule
  def self.child_one
    ParentModule::ChildModuleOne
  end

  def self.child_two
    ParentModule::ChildModuleTwo
  end
end

module ParentModule::ChildModuleOne
  def self.do_this
    # ...
  end
end

module ParentModule::ChildModuleTwo
  def self.do_that
    # ...
  end
end
```

This allows me to use a simple "namespace" syntax like this:

```rb
ParentModule.child_one.do_this
ParentModule.child_two.do_that
# etc
```

Now I'm wondering if there is any built-in functionality or dependency that could help me abstract away this behaviour.

For the record, I have already tried using [`forwardable`](https://github.com/ruby/forwardable) and `alias` with no luck.

```rb
# example using forwardable
def_delegator self, ParentModule::ChildModuleOne, :child_one
def_delegator self, ParentModule::ChildModuleTwo, :child_two

# example using alias
alias :child_one ParentModule::ChildModuleOne
alias :child_two ParentModule::ChildModuleTwo
```

Comment: Can there be many children for the same parent?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes there can be, but they would have different names.

Comment: Can you extend your example snippet with this new info?

Comment: To me personally, `ParentModule.child_one.do_this` does not look significantly better than `ParentModule::ChildModuleOne.do_this`, especially given the cost. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? You have hundreds of these parent-child relationships and you'd like to avoid writing out a getter method for each? If so, you could have a 3 LOC metaprogramming method which would define the getters for you when you do, say, something like this: `alias_modules ChildModuleOne: :child_one, ChildModuleTwo: :child_two`.

Comment: Even better if you can infer the getter name from the module name: `alias_modules :ChildOne, :ChildTwo`

Comment: BTW, the namespace syntax is the one you're avoiding, `Parent::Child`. The one you want, `Parent.child.do_this` is usually called "dot notation"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes I think I might have to do some metaprogramming to achieve this. As for the semantics, I do mean dot notation indeed. Essentially I wish there was a way of scoping methods in a module.

Comment: I understand the *what*, but not the *why*. ***Why*** do you want to reference a module as `ParentModule.child_one` instead of `ParentModule::ChildOne`? There are many ways I could think to achieve this (e.g. using `method_missing`), but there's no "definitive" solution like a `const_added` hook that I'm aware of.

Comment: @TomLord I'm trying to use a resource-based hierarchy for an API wrapper and I'd like to have different levels of importance between the module and the resources, such as `SomeCompany::SomeProduct.top_level_resource.sub_resource`. But maybe I'm thinking too much and `SomeCompany::SomeProduct::TopLevelResource.sub_resource` is just fine.

Comment: @kplattret if you nest the modules inside of `ParentModule` and appropriately load them they will be accessible by name e.g. outside of `ParentModule` you will need to call `ParentModule::ChildModuleOne` but inside `ParentModule` `ChildModuleOne` would be sufficient. Then you could construct a top level DSL to provide access but I think that having this DSL return the class is a bit obtuse. Instead I assume responsibility is separated appropriately that you should be able to provide a `ParentModule.do_this` which would leverage the internals of `ChildModuleOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must you use modules? It may be more convenient to use classes, as that would allow you to use the [Class::inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback.

```
class Parent
  def self.inherited(child)
    puts "child=#{child} in Parent"
    define_singleton_method(child.to_s.downcase.to_sym) { child }
  end
end
```

```
class Child1 < Parent
  puts "creating Child1"
  def self.whoami?
    puts "Me, child 1"
  end
end

child=Child1 in Parent
creating Child1
```

```
class Child2 < Parent
  puts "creating Child2"
  def self.whoami?
    puts "Me, child 2"
  end
end

child=Child2 in Parent
creating Child2
```

```
Parent.child1.whoami?

Me, child 1
```

```
Parent.child2.whoami?

Me, child 2
```

Comment: Note that I am not advocating this approach over writing, for example, `Parent::Child1.whoami?`, for a module `Parent::Child1`.

Comment: This actually works very well for my use case, thank you.